# Ruby 2D arrays need some explanation please

Tags: arrays, ruby, pipe

I have recently started working with 2D arrays in Ruby. Can someone explain why total is set to 0 in this case and also what function has "do" and "double pipes" in this case?

Thank you! See below.

```
def two_d_sum(arr)
 total = 0
  
 arr.each do |sub_array|
    sub_array.each do |num|
      total += num
    end
  end
  return total
end
```

Comment: The `do` indicates a block is being passed to the `each` method. This is _super-important_ in Ruby.  See [Ruby guides](https://www.rubyguides.com/2016/02/ruby-procs-and-lambdas/) for an overview of them.

Comment: Whatever project this is about it is evident that you should put this aside and take your time to learn basic ruby.  Ruby is different enough that my previous coding experiences simply could not jump start me  beyond the basics. KEEP AT IT!  The more you learn the more fun it becomes. Ruby is Fun! - not a word I ever used to describe JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Total is being set to 0 so that you can add to it using the `+=` operator inside of the block.

The `do || ...end` syntax is a block of code that is being passed to the `each` method. `each` runs the block of code for each item inside of the array. So here you are looping through each outer array then you are looping through the inner array and adding the value to `total`.

In ruby most people don't use `return` at the end of the method because the last value is always returned.

Here are a few other ways this same method could be implemented.

```
# flatten the 2D array into a normal array then sum
def two_d_sum(arr)
  arr.flatten.sum
end

# inject 0 with the sum of the arrays
def two_d_sum(arr)
  arr.inject(0) do |memo, array|
    memo + array.sum
  end
end
```

The `inject` example might be a bit confusing while you are learning, but the idea is that the block is run for each item in array and the return value of the block is passed as 'memo' for the next loop, and at the end the 'memo' is returned.